# Query for finding latest record in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a currency table I need to find the latest record of conversion rate which is less than given particular date

**Input table structure** given below:

| id | baseCur | Curr | rate | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | INR | USD | 81 | 2022-11-09 |
| 2 | INR | USD | 82 | 2022-11-08 |
| 3 | INR | USD | 80 | 2022-11-06 |
| 4 | INR | CAD | 56 | 2022-11-05 |
| 5 | INR | RUB | .74 | 2022-11-04 |
| 6 | INR | CAD | 57 | 2022-11-12 |

**Problem statement:**

I need to **find all latest currencies rate** that is less than 2022-11-09.On any given date there will be only conversation rate for any particular currency

so expected output

| id | baseCur | Curr | rate | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | INR | USD | 82 | 2022-11-08 |
| 4 | INR | CAD | 56 | 2022-11-05 |
| 5 | INR | RUB | .74 | 2022-11-04 |

**Explanantion of output :**

Id 1,6 rejected : cause they are greater than 2022-11-09 date

Id 3 rejected cause we have one more record for INR to CAD in row 2 and its date is more new to Id 3

Comment: It's easy to determine by using **window functions** if DB version is **8.0+**

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan thanks for the help. can you please tell me a bit more

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function such as **`DENSE_RANK()`** if DB version is **`8.0+`** in order to determine the latest records by using the query below

```
WITH t AS
(
 SELECT t.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY baseCur, Curr ORDER BY date DESC) AS dr
   FROM t
  WHERE date < '2022-11-09' 
)
SELECT id, baseCur, Curr, rate, date
  FROM t
 WHERE dr = 1
```

But, notice that this query returns the ties(equal date values) as well if there is any.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/uAoDRjrS)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Beside the option to use a window function for that, you could also use a subquery. In the subquery, you will catch every currency with the latest date:

```
SELECT 
curr, MAX(yourdate) maxDate
FROM yourtable
WHERE yourdate < '2022-11-09' 
GROUP BY curr;
```

This query will produce this outcome:

| Curr | maxDate |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2022-11-08 |
| 4 | 2022-11-05 |
| 5 | 2022-11-04 |

This result can be used by applying a `JOIN` clause or `IN` clause from a main query.

This will add the other columns.

```
SELECT y.id, y.baseCur, y.curr, y.rate, y.yourdate
FROM yourtable y 
JOIN (SELECT 
curr, MAX(yourdate) maxDate
FROM yourtable
WHERE yourdate < '2022-11-09' 
GROUP BY curr) maxDates
ON y.curr = maxDates.curr 
AND y.yourdate = maxDates.maxDate
ORDER BY id;
```

Thus, the complete intended result will be created:

| id | baseCur | Curr | rate | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | INR | USD | 82 | 2022-11-08 |
| 4 | INR | CAD | 56 | 2022-11-05 |
| 5 | INR | RUB | .74 | 2022-11-04 |

To point that out: I think using a window function should be prefered if possible.

They just have the "disadvantage" older DB's don't provide them and they often differ depending on the DB type.

So, if a query is required that works always on each DB type and DB version, this way of using a subquery becomes helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the desired output using subquery, as shown below, which fetches latest record from each currency.

```
-- 1. Based on id column
SELECT * FROM sometable as t WHERE t.id = 
(SELECT MAX(id) FROM sometable WHERE Curr = t.Curr and date < '2022-11-09');
-- 2. Based on date column
SELECT * FROM sometable as t WHERE t.date = 
(SELECT MAX(date) FROM sometable WHERE Curr = t.Curr and date < '2022-11-09');
```

Comment: This query will not work

Comment: Valid syntax now, still incorrect result.

Comment: If id field is auto incremented, we can fetch latest record using id instead of filtering by date. Hence id 3 record is the latest record for USD though date is lesser than id 2.